# Setting up foreign key in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 models and want to create a foreign key relationship. Basically each note should be assigned to a user.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserNotes")]
public class UserNotes
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Added { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Edited { get; set; }  
}
```

When I attempt to add new user note I get:
*The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'UserId' on type 'note.DO.Models.UserNotes' is not valid. The navigation property 'UserProfile' was not found on the dependent type 'note.DO.Models.UserNotes'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.*

I have tried a lot of combinations including those found in similar questions but none of them worked.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with asp.net?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this :

```
public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }
```

This way, you pair foreign key property with navigation property.

Edit : you can also write it like this :

```
[ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
```

Those two snippets gives the same result. Your error message says that "UserProfile" property is missing, you just have to add it.

Comment: Why do we need to use the virtual keyword when declaring foreign keys? Any chance you could answer that?