# Entity Framework not loading FK into entities diagram

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL diagram that looks like this where `Id_Cajero` from `CortesDeCaja` have a foreing key with `Usuarios` table on `Id` column

[image: Sql diagram]

And I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project where I load these 4 tables and get this Entities diagram:

[image: Entity generated Diagram]

As you can see the relationship between `CortesDeCaja` and `Usuarios` is not present. What could I be missing?

Edit
Can anyone help me please? i'm still stucked on this.

Comment: Check the SQL database schema, see if the foreign relation was already saved, check also in the diagram "select  `Usuarios` table" or even, [check this question and his accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517451/setting-up-foreign-key-in-asp-net-mvc-4).

Comment: Yeap @Mauricio, is already saved, actually I can test it creating a new query inside MSSMS, and using the Query Editor loads correctly the relationship